# Android service keeps blocked indefinetly in a thread.join

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to build a function that determines if there's telephony network connectivity, but if it fails on detecting I want it to keep on trying to detect it for a certain amount of time, once this time is passed and it hasn't been detected it would be returned that it hasn't been detected, on the other hand if its detected, the checking of its detection will be stopped and what would be returned is that connectivity exists.

I think I could achieve that with the following code:

```
public static String operatornetwork = null;
static boolean finish = false;
static boolean telephonynetworkfound = false;

[...]


       final CountDownTimer cdt=new CountDownTimer(60 * 1000, 5 * 1000) 
       {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
            {
                operatornetwork = tel.getNetworkOperator();
                if ((operatornetwork != null) && (!operatornetwork.equals(""))) 
                {
                    telephonynetworkfound = true;
                    finish=true;

                }
            }

            public void onFinish() 
            {
                operatornetwork = tel.getNetworkOperator();
                if ((operatornetwork != null) && (!operatornetwork.equals(""))) {
                    telephonynetworkfound = true;

                }
                finish=true;
            }
        };

        cdt.start();


        final Thread welcomeThread = new Thread() 
        {


            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                try 
                {
                    super.run();


                    while (true) 
                    {

                        if (finish)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        sleep(3000);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {

                } finally 
                {


                }
            }
        };
        welcomeThread.start();
        try 
        {
            welcomeThread.join();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return telephonynetworkfound;
```

I thought that as the infinite loop is running on a separate thread it wouldn't block the app, and finish iss supposed to be true at least onFinish in the CountDownTimer, but it looks that the block comes in welcomeThread.join(), but I cannot be sure because whenever I reach the welcomeThread.join in debugging I get the error frames not available for unsuspended thread, even if it that's only a debugging error the app doesn't go further than that point.

Any idea on what might be happening?

Comment: Is possible that the thread with the infinite loop will cache the value of the `finish` variable which means that it will never be `true`. You should at least declare this variable as `volatile` or use an `AtomicBoolean` instead.

Comment: @Titus, it didn't work, anyway I managed to solve it another way, thanks for your tip.